# Spring Boot - Rest Api occasionally adds Error Object to a response

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I use spring-boot-starter-web (Spring Boot 2.3.0.RELEASE) and my Controller looks like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1")
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getObject() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new Object());
    }
}
```

I've noticed that sometimes in a browser I catch a response like

```
{}{"timestamp":"2021-03-11T13:39:08.100+00:00","status":200,"error":"OK","message":"","path":"/v1"}
```

This reproduces randomly - most time I get a correct JSON `{}`.
Could you advise how to disable adding of the second JSON and what can be a reason for this behavior? Is it a bug?

[image]

Comment: Looks like the meta-data on the response itself. In the angular httpclient you can define that the response contains the payload ({}) and the reponse meta data itself (json with the status code)

Comment: Thanks, I consider this option to cut the second JSON from a response, but I'd like to be able to constantly reproduce this answer. Even a browser is confused with this reponse.

Comment: Are you getting same weird response when calling from terminal? If so, please post build gradle/pom.xml and other config classes from your project

Comment: With spring/boot you get this behavior consistently if you have a controller that handles the /error redirect. I have not found a solution yet.